# Iterate over object array and return to jade template

Tags: express, pug

I have an array I need that I need to pass to express, render and then iterate through on the Jade side to display all the results, however the below function does not work. It only displays one piece of data, five times from the array. The expected behaviour is that it would loop through the array and display one of each object in the template.

Is the syntax for the jade and express correct? The documentation is quite light.

Screenshot
[image]

Express

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
  weekendPlans(function(err, theWeekend) {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log(theWeekend);
      res.render('index', {theWeekend : theWeekend});
});
```

Jade

```
  h2 On This Weekend
  .scroll
    each result, i in theWeekend
      div.title
        #[a(target="_blank" href="#{theWeekend.url}") #{theWeekend.title}]
        p WHEN: #{theWeekend.selectedDate}
```

Data

```
{ _id: 56fe9fe71f84acc2564b9fe8,
  url: 'http://www.timeoutshanghai.com/features/Blog-Food__Drink/35271/Baristas-showcase-latte-art-in-Shanghai.html',
  title: 'TIMEOUT',
  selectedDate: Sat Apr 02 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST),
  __v: 0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Jade file, you are iterating over the data object, which loops once for each key-value pair in your object. If you only want one entry for the data object, try this instead:

```
div.title
  #[a(target="_blank" href="#{theWeekend.url}") #{theWeekend.title}]
  p WHEN: #{theWeekend.selectedDate}
```

it should work.

Comment: I tried that previously and it gave me five results still except with no data. Very confusing. Any other ideas?

Comment: What is the output of console.log(theWeekend); ?

Comment: The output is the data in the original question

Comment: And what do you expect to be displayed on the page?

Comment: Should just be the one object, not five

Comment: I've edited my answer. But allow me one more question: Why does your question talk about an array and iterating through all entries?

Comment: I was wondering the same as you Nicole. Added my answer before you made your edit and thought about removing it since it now is mostly a duplicate of yours. But mine added some extra information so I'll let it be, maybe it's useful to someone.

Comment: Sorry @tomtom, I didn't see your answer until I had made my edit - I got pretty confused about the claim that the data passed was an array. Should have realized earlier that it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

What array? All I can see is an object. You are looping through one object. And for every key in the object you make jade print out a div with an anchor and a paragraph. Since your object holds five keys, you get five divs.

That is why when you wrote `result.key` it gave you nothing, because that does not exist. In that scenario `result[1]` would have given you the url. And when you wrote `theWeekend.key` it gave you the same text every time.

If you only have one object you don't need a loop. You should write:

```
.scroll
      div.title
        #[a(target="_blank" href="#{theWeekend.url}") #{theWeekend.title}]
        p WHEN: #{theWeekend.selectedDate}
```

Comment: I will have more objects in the future, sorry if that wasn't clear,

Comment: Well, then. In the future when "theWeekend" is in fact an array of objects you should use result.url, result.title, etc... inside your jade-loop. Good luck!